# Math-Bio: Reference/Example needed for a reaction-diffusion system coupled to a conservation law

Tags: mathematical-modeling, parabolic-pde, mathematical-biology

DISCLAIMER: I also made a [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/114343/in-search-of-motivation-examples-from-nature) about it in biology stack exchange but I'm not sure whether that forum is the most appropriate. Hence I thought to share my question here as well.

While looking at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.12660), I came across with the following:

> Examples of reaction-diffusion systems (1)-(2), falling into the class
> of systems we are interested in, are for instance the Brusselator, the
> Schnakenberg, the Gray-Scott and the Gierer-Meinhardt model coupled to
> a conservation law coming for instance from ecology.

Although I googled a lot, I couldn't find any example/reference from ecology which satisfies the above. Having a motivation can help someone gain easier intuition on the expected results, which is really important.

**Question:** What are some examples of reaction-diffusion systems, coupled to a conservation law, coming from biology? I'm looking for a rather simple reference or examples from daily life (if any).

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is cancer models, for example, https://doi.org/10.1201/9781315365404. The reaction term is usually a growth/death dynamics. The conservation law is often related to mass and usually comes from the model derivation or the transition between states. Classic textbooks on mathematical biology from Leah Edelstein-Keshet and James Murray also have examples of these.

Comment: @Paichu Many thanks for the suggestion. I will have a look on that!